# Safari Bug for text-shadow?

Tags: safari, glyphicons, css

I'm having an issue where safari is not rendering a complete text-shadow on a custom glyphicon like chrome or ff does. I attach an image of the button.

Do you know if there's any known bug or anything related to that?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Upd: Happens in Safari 6.1.4, not in the new version 7.0.4, but anyway I have to fix that!

Comment: amazing thing is that other icons don't have that issue, anything else about that?

Answer (score 0):

In Safari it simply takes webkit. But still if it creates problem then please try with the below mentioned css.

**Text Shadow in Safari**

`.selector {
    text-shadow: #666666 5px 5px 5px; /* Just an example */
}`

Please try providing the color first the dimensions and check whether it helps you or not.

Cheers :)

Comment: I'm already using the text-shadow property. The question is about an issue happening using the text-shadow property and only in Safari. Every other browser renders perfectly. I'm not asking for code to fix it, just to know if there's some explanation to that issue, as it happens in Safari 6.1.4 and not in the latest version. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Yes, that's been a problem in the lower versions of Safari browser. Without css hacks, that creates issues.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and found an article what mentioned a very easy solution: use RGB code instead of hex color code.

Example:

`.selector { text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgb(91,91,91); }`